# Modifying pandas row value based on its length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in my pandas dataframe with the following values that represent hours worked in a week.

```
0                             40
1                  40h / week
2      46.25h/week on average
3                             11
```

I would like to check every row, and if the length of the value is larger than 2 digits - extract the number of hours only from it.
I have tried the following:

```
df['Hours_per_week'].apply(lambda x: (x.extract('(\d+)') if(len(str(x)) > 2) else x))
```

However I am getting the **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extract'** error.

Comment: The method 'extract' does not exist for strings. You need to define some function or method that will extract the digits from the string.

Comment: By "*larger than 2 digits*" do you mean that you want to avoid extracting the number in the first and last row?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could ensure having `h` after the number:

```
df['Hours_per_week'].str.extract(r'(\d{2}\.?\d*)h', expand=False)
```

Output:

```
0      NaN
1       40
2    46.25
3      NaN
Name: Hours_per_week, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the series data are strings, try this:

```
df['Hours_per_week'].str.extract('(\d+)')
```

Comment: Maybe he needs a Series

Comment: @ansev what do you mean? This returns a series.

Answer (score 0):

Why not immediately extract float pattern i.e. `\d+\.?\d+` ?

```py
>>> s = pd.Series(['40', '40h / week', '46.25h/week on average', '11'])
>>> s.str.extract("(\d+\.?\d+)")
       0
0     40
1     40
2  46.25
3     11
```

2 digits will still match either way.